# mongodb: IndexKeysBuilder for Array elements without string constants?

Tags: indexing, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to eliminate hardcoded property names in my code and stuck with indexes for nested Arrays.

string version looks pretty simple:

```
DocumentCaollection.EnsureIndex("ChangesList._id");
```

but i have no idea how to write this with IndexKeysBuilder:

```
new IndexKeysBuilder<TransactionEntity>().Ascending(x => x.ChangesList. ???? )
```

For example, this code compiles but fails on runtime:

```
new IndexKeysBuilder<TransactionEntity>().Ascending(x => x.ChangesList.Select(y => y.Id))
```

with following exception:

Unable to determine the serialization information for the expression: (TransactionEntity x) => Enumerable.Select(x.ChangesList, (TransactionItem y) => y.Id)

Comment: I guess you don't really have a property named "_id" on your types, only in mongo. So there's no way really to add it in a non-hardcoded way.

Comment: Id is changed to _id automatically by mongodb. For simple keys it works fine

Comment: the typed IndexKeyBuilder does that, but it doesn't support nested arrays. You can do it yourself in a typed way but not if the property on your class is different than the one on the document.